# FirebaseCrash - new feature?

Tags: firebase-console, firebase-crash-reporting

Today when uploading proguard mapping file to firebase console I suddenly saw something new [image]

But link "Learn more" directs to unchanged FirebaseCrash docs

They forget to update docs or feature not available yet?

PS: Does anyone know how to change language in firebase console? Russian localization is terrible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion here.  This is an unfortunate case of some experiments and designs accidentally being pushed to production prior to their general availability.  Stay tuned for actual, working new features.  :-)